# How do I extract the second to last occurrence of a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, function, find

I'm using MySQL 5.5.37.  I have a TEXT column that contains values resembling ...

```
... "id":"51b21a0710340adf6501db67"}},"created":"2014-08-22T15:42:57.969Z","id":"53f76502f82c7abf3d01fba5"},"uri":"/v1.1/events/53f76502f82c7abf3d01fba5"}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to extract the 32-character value immediately after the second to last '"id":' string (without the quotes surrounding the 32 character item).  What is the easiest way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to find the second to last occurrence, and use [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) to cut out the first 32 characters that follow (although I suspect you only want 24);

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '"id":"', -2), 32) FROM bop
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8433a/4).